# Sort results of a query by date without duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

let's say that this is the result of one of my query:

```
+------+--------------------------+
| ID   | STARTED_TIME             |
+------+--------------------------+
| 9870 | 17-07-05 16:15:30,040000 |
+------+--------------------------+
| 9871 | 17-07-06 16:15:25,586000 |
+------+--------------------------+
| 9872 | 17-07-07 15:08:08,370000 |
+------+--------------------------+
| 9873 | 17-07-07 16:15:20,208000 |
+------+--------------------------+
| 9874 | 17-07-08 16:15:22,166000 |
+------+--------------------------+
| 9875 | 17-07-09 16:15:29,812000 |
+------+--------------------------+
```

What I would like to do is remove the duplicates when the STARTED_TIME is the same DAY and take the last entry for that day. Exemple:

```
+------+--------------------------+
| ID   | STARTED_TIME             |
+------+--------------------------+
| 9870 | 17-07-05 16:15:30,040000 |
+------+--------------------------+
| 9871 | 17-07-06 16:15:25,586000 |
+------+--------------------------+
| 9873 | 17-07-07 16:15:20,208000 |
+------+--------------------------+
| 9874 | 17-07-08 16:15:22,166000 |
+------+--------------------------+
| 9875 | 17-07-09 16:15:29,812000 |
+------+--------------------------+
```

Note this is in an Oracle database. I am asking too much here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you already have code tried out? Also have a look at SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: Try to use TO_DATE . Convert the started_time to date and then get distinct values.

Comment: @Tenzin I have looked into DISTINCT but I couldn't come up with a solution that satisfied what I want here. Thanks though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, the TRUNC function removes the time portion of a date. We also need a window function to provide a counter that resets every time the day changes:

```
SELECT
  z.id,
  z.started_time
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    t.*, 
    TRUNC(started_time) as started_day, --you can remove this column if you want
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRUNC(started_time) ORDER BY started_time DESC) as rown 
  FROM mytable t
) z
WHERE z.rown=1
ORDER BY id
```

TRUNC removes the time part, leaving only the date, ROW_NUMBER numbers all rows with an incrementing number where the date is the same (partition by) and the rows are ordered in descending order of time so the latest gets rownumber = 1

Then the WHERE clause of the outer query selects only rows where the row number is 1, i.e. the latest time

I chose latest because your example did also. If you want earliest, your query must say `partiton by trunc(started_time) order by started_time asc` not desc

If you want more info on how the query is working, just run the inner query and take a look at the data. There's a column i put in there that has no purpose for your outer query, but if you just running the inner query it helps explain how it works

Comment: Thanks alot @Caius Jard! I got it working and it's doing exactly what I wanted :) Only thing though on line 11 I don't think it's ") as z" but rather simply ") z".

Comment: Amended; thanks for the feedback! Must have had a brain delay there; though it's legal on many databases, it isn't on oracle, and given that I learnt most my SQL on 9g, i've never learnt to "as x" to alias a table so I've no idea why I wrote that. Old age..